# SqlMembershipProvider: use my own database as user store database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, membership-provider

I'm developing an **ASP.NET** application with **Visual Studio 2008 SP1** and **C#**. I'm also using **Sql Server 2008 SP1**.

I'm trying to add the tables created with the command `aspnet_regsql -S (local) -E -A m` to my own database.

If I run that command it will create a database (**Aspnetdb** database) with four tables. I want to know if there is a command that creates those tables in my own database (called **myDatabase**, for example).

And, when the tables are created. How can I connect authentication to **myDatabase**?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aspnet_regsql-C "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" ...
```

will generate in database given by connection string

Also you should configure MembershipProvider to work with your database. Just add this to your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
      userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <add 
          name="SqlProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName="SqlServices"
          applicationName="MyApplication"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
          passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the output from "[aspnet_regsql -?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28VS.80%29.aspx)", there is a paramter -d that you can use, thus making your command:

```
 aspnet_regsql -S (local) -E -A -d myDatabase
```

Alternatively you could call it with the "-sqlexportonly filenamegoes.here" parameter to generate a Sql Script that you can review and then apply to your database:

```
 aspnet_regsql -S (local) -E -A -sqlexportonly output.sql
```

The MSDN documentation for [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) explains how to change where it looks for its database, specifically the line *connectionStringName="SqlServices"* in the Example.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `-C <connection string>` option instead of the `-S (local)` option and specify a database name in the connection string. This allows to to run the create scripts on an existing database. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28VS.80%29.aspx) for the aspnet_regsql options.