# VB.Net 4.0 SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

First time poster. I'm currently working on a website for class that I would eventually like to publish and go live with.

The basic premise with the website is a user can register for a new account and then login with that account. I built the website with Visual Studio 2010 and used their login controls (login, login status, createuserwizard) etc.

Apparently when I create a new user (per the wizard) it writes and saves the data somewhere but I'm not sure where. I have a database I created called `Users` and I would like to take the information that was entered (First name, Last name, Email, etc.) and write it to the `Users` database. After searching around it appears I have to use a stored procedure and then call that stored procedure when the "Register" button is clicked.

Can anybody shed some light on what this stored procedure would look like and how I would call it? Just the basic syntax would help and I can fill in the specific details of what I'm writing to the DB on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: What membership provider are you using? If it's [`SqlMemberShipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) the new user is created in your sql-server database. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs

Comment: i believe it's SqlMemberShipProvider.

Comment: Whoops sorry for the double reply.  Didnt know enter acted as clicking the Add Comment Button.  Should I just not worry about the stored procedures and trying to have it write to my own database then since it is already writing to its own?

Answer (score 0):

Your default connection is probably LocalSqlServer and is set in the machine config.

To explicitly set it to this you you can add the following to your web config. Note the first part that clears out the default value. (this should leave you connecting to the same database, you are just expliciting setting it rather than using the default)

```
<system.web>
            ...

                <membership 
                 defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
                 <providers>
                    <clear/>
                    <add name="SqlProvider"
                        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                        connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                        enablePasswordReset="true"
                        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                        requiresUniqueEmail="false" />
                        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                        passwordFormat="Hashed"
                        minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
                        minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0"
                        passwordStrengthReqularExpression="0"
                        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                        applicationName="/" />
                </providers>
            </membership>
            ...
        </system.web>
```

to override it see
[SqlMembershipProvider: use my own database as user store database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333705/sqlmembershipprovider-use-my-own-database-as-user-store-database)